# How many projects can you run on Firebase Flame Plan?

Tags: firebase

You can create b/w 5-10 projects on the Spark Plan - but what about the Flame Plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There's no limit (that I know of) to the number of projects you can have on a paid plan.